# Remove duplicate record from MySQL result using LIKE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

How do i remove duplicate record from MySQL result using LIKE clause?

```
$lname = $_POST["lname"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT fname, lname, email FROM users WHERE lname LIKE '$lname%' ORDER BY lname ASC");
```

but still showing duplicate record?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` should not show duplicate rows .. what exactly do you mean by duplicate record?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT not working with LIKE clause

Comment: can you post the results of your query?  Like if you run it from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

For one thing [watch out for SQL injection!](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Secondly, You would need to do a `Delete`

For third:  There can be *many* people who have a last name that has the same inside to it.